# C# DataContract DataMember EmitDefaultValue=false still outputting nil

Tags: c#, xml, jaxb, datacontract

I have some very simple code.

```
    //File Company.cs
    using System;
    using Sharpen;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    namespace XPathTest
    {
        [DataContract(IsReference=true)]
        public class Company
        {
            [DataMember]
            public AList<Person> employees {get; set;}

            public Company ()
            {
                employees = new AList<Person>();
            }
        }
    }

    //File Employee.cs
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    namespace XPathTest
    {
        [DataContract(IsReference=true)]
        public class Employee :  Person
        {
            public Employee ()
            {
            }
        }
    }


    //File Manager.cs

    using System;
    using Sharpen;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    namespace XPathTest
    {
        [DataContract(IsReference=true)]
        public class Manager : Person
        {
            [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
            public AList<Person> employees { get; set; }

            public Manager ()
            {
                employees = new AList<Person>();
            }

            public void AddEmployee(Person employee)
            {
                employees.Add (employee);
            }
        }
    }


    //File Person.cs

    using System;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    namespace XPathTest
    {
        [DataContract(IsReference=true)]
        public class Person
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int SSNum { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string name { get; set; }

            [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
            public Person manager {get; set;}

            public Person ()
            {

            }

            public void SetManager(Person manager) 
            {
                this.manager = manager;
            }

        }
    }



//File Main.cs
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using XPathTest;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Read and write purchase orders.
        Test t = new Test();
    t.MarshalCompany ("po.xml");

    }

    public Company BuildCompany ()
    {
        Company company = new Company();
        Manager employee1 = new Manager();
        employee1.SSNum = 1337;
        employee1.name ="Jane Doe";
        company.employees.Add(employee1);

        Employee employee2 = new Employee();
        employee2.SSNum = 8008132;
        employee2.name = "John Smith";
        employee2.SetManager(employee1);
        company.employees.Add(employee2);

        Employee employee3 = new Employee();
        employee3.SSNum = 1138;
        employee3.name = "Anne Jones";
        employee3.SetManager(employee1);
        company.employees.Add(employee3);

        employee1.AddEmployee(employee2);
        employee1.AddEmployee(employee3);

        Manager manager1 = new Manager();
        manager1.SSNum = 314;
        manager1.name = "Boss Hog";
        //manager1.setManager(manager1);
        manager1.AddEmployee(employee1);
        company.employees.Add(manager1);

        return company;
    }

    public void MarshalCompany(string filename)
    {
        Company po = BuildCompany ();
        System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer (po.GetType ());

        using (FileStream stream = File.Create (filename)) 
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, po);
        }
    }
```

And I happen to be getting this output...

```
<Company xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XPathTest" z:Id="i1">
<employees>
<Person i:type="Manager" z:Id="i2">
<SSNum>1337</SSNum>
<manager i:nil="true"/>
<name>Jane Doe</name>
<employees>
<Person i:type="Employee" z:Id="i3">
<SSNum>8008132</SSNum>
<manager i:type="Manager" z:Ref="i2"/>
<name>John Smith</name>
</Person>
<Person i:type="Employee" z:Id="i4">
<SSNum>1138</SSNum>
<manager i:type="Manager" z:Ref="i2"/>
<name>Anne Jones</name>
</Person>
</employees>
</Person>
<Person i:type="Employee" z:Ref="i3"/>
<Person i:type="Employee" z:Ref="i4"/>
<Person i:type="Manager" z:Id="i5">
<SSNum>314</SSNum>
<manager i:nil="true"/>
<name>Boss Hog</name>
<employees>
<Person i:type="Manager" z:Ref="i2"/>
</employees>
</Person>
</employees>
</Company>
```

Why are the  [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)] attributes not working?

The output shows things like

```
<manager i:nil="true"/>
```

which I do not want for reasons of size, and compatibility with what jaxb outputs in the even that something is null (no element).

All the stuff I've read on MSDN and even other stackoverflow pages says this should work, but it is not. I would appreciate anyone who could help me figure out why the nil elements are still present. The code posted there is working code, for me, if you have the Sharpen namespace from the "ngit" project (for Sharpen.AList, which is just a wrapper for Collections.List). I've been doing a lot of java/c# lately.

The reason I'm interested in this is because I have a large large huge amount of data which is basically some java classes serialized with Jaxb 2.2.7, which I send over TCP to a C# client which has analogous classes of the in java. The goal is to unmarshal that data right into the c# classes. Unfortunately, I could not find a method in jaxb of naturally creating a universal reference tracker per object serialized, and had to manually write an @XmlAdapter for each class I wanted tracked and referred to. It seems that DataContract does this naturally and quite easily. However, the JAXB doesn't put references to null elements in the output xml, and I'd like to make sure that the DataContract stuff mimics the same behavior.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I am running into this bug, as I am using Monodevelop 3.0.3.2.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7999

Who would've guessed. I tested it in VC# 2012 and it works fine. Fails in Monodevelop.